# How to properly declare and annotate this type?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following class:

```
_Types = ['Null', 'Bool', 'Int', 'Float', 'Decimal']
Type = Enum('Type', {v:i for i,v in enumerate(_Types)})

class Literal:
    def __init__(self, _type: Type, _val:Optional[str]=None):
        self._type = _type
```

However, it shows that `_type: Type` is not allowed. How would I allow the output type to be one of the `Enum` values?

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
Type = Enum('Type', {v:i for i,v in enumerate(_Types)})
```

You actually create an Enum called Type. It is same as running below code

```
import enum


class Type(enum.Enum):
    Null = 0
    Bool = 1
    Int = 2
    Float = 3
    Decimal = 4
```

So when you use it in type hinting, you actually require input to be one of enum types, not the classes in your list. Example:

```
literal_1 = Literal(_type=Type.Null, _val="some string value")  # no warning, valid input
literal_2 = Literal(_type=Null, _val="some string value")  # warning, invalid input
```

If your types are static, you could use typing.Union. In this case I assume you have your own class types called `[Null, Bool, Int, Float, Decimal]`

```
from typing import Union
from some_other_module import Null, Bool, Int, Float, Decimal


Type = Union[Null, Bool, Int, Float, Decimal]

class Literal:
    def __init__(self, _type: Type, _val:Optional[str]=None):
        self._type = _type
```

Comment: could you please clarify or modify the answer, as the above is invalid python, particularly the `class Type`.